# Name of a greek spice that sounds like "bakari"

Tags: spices, greek-cuisine

Many years ago, we brought back from Greece a spice that was suggested to us for preparing the Moussaka. The greek who sold it to us called it "bakari". Now we have used all our stock and I've tried to buy it from Belgium, but I can't find it. Anyone knows the name of this spice in English (I've tried to google it with different spellings, but I didn't find it on the Web).

By the way, it looks like small (0.5 cm) brown balls.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The spice you are looking for is called Allspice or Piment, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allspice.

[image]

The Greek name is μπαχάρι, [pronounced](http://www.forvo.com/word/%CE%BC%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%87%CE%AC%CF%81%CE%B9/) `bakhari`.